# What's the purpose of lodash invoke in this code?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am seeing a piece of code:

```
import _invoke from 'lodash/invoke'

const format = _invoke(Intl, 'DateTimeFormat')
```

And for me it looks like it can be replaced by a simpler variant:

```
const format = Intl.DateTimeFormat()
```

The most obvious reason I see is `_invoke` won't throw an error if `DateTimeFormat` is not available, e.g. `undefined`.

However, I am afraid it can work in a different way when changed to latter because it's not just a function but a method of an object?

So, why the author of the code could've used it that way?

Comment: Ultimately only the author knows…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression indeed looks functionally identical to

```js
Intl?.DateTimeFormat?.()
```

The author may have wanted to use lodash because they considered it more "idiomatic" in some way, or they may have been developing for a browser version that doesn't support nullish coalescing operators and wanted to avoid constructs like `Intl && Intl.DateTimeFormat && Intl.DateTimeFormat()` etc.

As @deceze put it, only the author knows.